# How to get the lastcolumn with data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot get my code to properly identify the last column with data. The Last Column should be `$Q$9` but when running the function I get `$M$9` as my Last Column. What am I doing wrong?

**Code**

```
Function Q3calls()

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("clientmenu")

lastrow = ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = ws.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 13), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
End With

Q3calls = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & wb.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A67"), rng, "<=" & wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B67")) 'q3

Exit Function

End Function
```

**Screen Shot of Range**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: Your code is looking at `Row` 8 and you're expecting the result of `Row` 9

Comment: Will the last column always be found in row **9**?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld the last row always changes, it is not always 9

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
lastrow = ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = ws.Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

With

```
With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

I'd also recommend defining your variables which you don't seem to have done in your function

```
Function Q3calls()
   Dim wb as Workbook
   Dim LastRow as Long, LastCol as Long
   Dim rng as Range

   set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    With wb.Sheets("clientmenu")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 13), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    End With

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Q3calls = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & .Range("A67"), rng, "<=" & .Range("B67")) 'q3
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Tom you are not qualifying the sheet on `Columns.Count` so if `ws` is not the active sheet this will fail.

Comment: @Damian - copy paste jobby. Have updated with fully qualified.

Comment: @tom I would like my range to start on `$M$8`. Your code is giving my values starting from `$A$1`. The last row is always changing as I add more customers to the list. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this Function also:**

```
Function LastCol(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**Then LastColumn would be**

```
lastcol = LastCol(wb.Sheets("clientmenu"))
```